# Conditional CSS style for images depending on their *original* width or height

Tags: html, image, css

How can I create such a CSS style for images that will only be applied to the images that have the *minimum original size* of a certain amount?

For instance, I want all the images that have *the original width* equal or more than 500px to have a certain css style. But others - not, that CSS style shouldn’t be applied to them.

Without javascript.

Comment: It is not possible to use conditional in CSS without preprocessors like Sass.

As long as you did not mention Sass or any other preprocessor in your question, the immediate awnser would be NO , you can not do that without javascript.

By the way why not use javascript?

Comment: @CaioSaldanha, why did you write "no" in capslock?

Answer (score 3):

I think you're asking if there's a CSS selector that could target images based on their saved dimensions rather than the displayed size i.e. ignore scaling.

Unfortunately there is nothing in CSS that can query such properties (yet).

One solution may be to name large images differently to small images, this way you can use the [[data-value] selector](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/). In this example I've match based on a dimension in the image path, but perhaps you could use `large` or something in the path?

```css
img {
  max-height: 200px;
  border: 5px solid black;
}


/* Target images with /640/ in the src path.*/

img[src*="/640/"] {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/510/any" alt="Image 1">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/440/480/any" alt="Image 2">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/640/680/any" alt="Image 3">
<img src="https://placeimg.com/440/420/any" alt="Image 4">
```

Can you elaborate on why you wish to represent large images differently so I can possibly provide a better answer?